# Getting "unmarshal failed" when trying to create first website post in Hugo after installation

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, hugo

I'm following the instructions at Hugo's Quickstart guide (https://gohugo.io/getting-started/quick-start/) but I keep getting this error message when I try to create a post:

```
unmarshal failed: Near line 1 (last key parsed 'theme'): expected value but found '\\' instead
```

I've posted some lines of my code below. The error message appears at the bottom. Could anyone help point out what I am doing wrong?

```
C:\Users\Scott\quickstart\MyHugoBlog\themes>git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/Scott/quickstart/MyHugoBlog/themes/.git/

C:\Users\Scott\quickstart\MyHugoBlog\themes>git submodule add https://github.com/dashdashzako/paperback.git
Cloning into 'C:/Users/Scott/quickstart/MyHugoBlog/themes/paperback'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 16, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Total 194 (delta 3), reused 9 (delta 1), pack-reused 178 eceiving objects:  53% (103/194)
Receiving objects: 100% (194/194), 466.30 KiB | 5.62 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (93/93), done.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in .gitmodules.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

C:\Users\Scott\quickstart\MyHugoBlog\themes>echo theme = \"paperback\" >> config.toml

C:\Users\Scott\quickstart\MyHugoBlog\themes>hugo new posts/my-first-post.md
Error: "C:\Users\Scott\quickstart\MyHugoBlog\themes\config.toml:1:1": unmarshal failed: Near line 1 (last key parsed 'theme'): expected value but found '\\' instead
```

Comment: From the pop-up text for [tag:git]: "Also, do not use this tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository." That fits this particular case, so I'll snip the tag. (There's nothing like that for the two markdown tags so I'll leave those alone.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you're following instructions meant for Unix-like systems on Windows. This command isn't doing what you want:

```
echo theme = \"paperback\" >> config.toml
```

Using Bash on Linux, for example, this appends

```
theme = "paperback"
```

to your `config.toml` file, creating it if necessary. That's what Hugo expects to find in the file.

However, using `cmd.exe` on Windows I get the backslashes included:

```
theme = \"paperback\"
```

And using PowerShell, I get something even stranger:

```
theme
=
\paperback\
```

Neither of these looks like valid [TOML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOML) to me, and both contain extraneous backslashes as referenced in your error message. I suggest you simply edit `config.toml` using your favourite text editor and add the expected

```
theme = "paperback"
```

line manually.

Answer (score 1):

The issue on my end was that the file wasn't created as UTF-8
Delete the config.toml file and recreate it manually on your text editor, then paste the content like: theme = "ananke"
should work

Comment: This fixed it for me.

Copied text, deleted file, and created a new one saved properly and it worked.